# Why can't I dispel this ward?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I seem to be having some (a lot) of difficulty dispelling wards on treasures in *Kingdoms of Amalur: Reckoning.* The problem is, after reading the tooltip ~3 times and **still** not understanding exactly what it was I was supposed to do, I figured I'd just learn as I went.

Sadly, this hasn't worked. At all. Even with my increased Dispel skill, I *still* fail on the dispels. **EVERY**. **SINGLE**. ***TIME***.

**How do I dispel these wards?**

Comment: I've found making potions that increase my dispelling skill help with this minigame to an extent.  When I'm going dungeon crawling, I take a stack of 3 or 4 of them along to make the harder chests easier.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What threw me about Dispelling is that it doesn't matter *where* you click. You don't have to click inside the circle when it's over the rune, you just have to click **period**.

Effectively, you're playing a circular version of Dance-Dance Revolution -- you want to click when the circle overlaps with the rune exactly. Missing a rune entirely will re-lock every unlocked rune immediately, meaning you'll have to do it again. Hit a bomb or run out of time, you detonate the ward.

The goal is to get all the runes clicked at once. I don't think it's possible for the order you click the runes to matter - as long as you're clicking them in order around the circle (and avoiding the bombs), you should dispel it in a revolution or two.

**Higher Difficulty**

Both the speed of the rotating ring and the time you have to activate all the runes change with level, with the speed increasing, and the time decreasing. Improving one's Dispelling skill has the opposite effect.

[image]
*Success!*

Comment: The order does matter to an extent - some of the runes "reset" faster than others.  On the easy wards, this dosen't make as much of a difference, but later on it does.  I believe the more "lines" are in the rune, the more complex it is and the faster its timer runs down.

Comment: @agent86 I agree - my point is that I can't conceive of a scenario where you would not want to *not* hit a particular rune.

Comment: I guess my display must be lagging. Because if I click when the circle is directly over the rune, nothing happens. But if I (for arguments sake, pretend the circle is rotating counterclockwise in your image) click when the circle is in the position it's *currently* in (in your image), it activates the rune. Make sense?

Comment: @Tristan I have the same problem but I think mine has more to do with my mouse. It's bad at clicking. Sometimes it double clicks, sometimes it doesn't click at all. Basically, I just auto-dispel every time. If I fail, my health is high enough now that it doesn't affect me much.

Comment: @RavenDreamer If the circle is moving fast enough it might be best to not try and click every rune on one circuit but instead do two on the first circuit and two on the second circuit. In that case you would want to do the "complicated" runes on the second circuit.

Comment: At first I was driving myself mad trying to move my mouse around the circle as well as time clicks. I wish the game told you instead of leaving you to learn by trial and error.