# How can I dispel a chest with my mouse?

Tags: pc, kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I dispel this ward?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50227/why-cant-i-dispel-this-ward)

I am having inmense trouble dispelling chests, even the ones that are labelled as easy. Sometimes if any, I get to click only ward.

Is this virtually impossible to do with my mouse, or am I just doing it totally wrong?

Right now, I am just taking the damage and curses to the chest, cause I am too much of a loot whore not to take the stuff ... but this has killed me a couple of times, specially when I have a curse that lowers my Magic Resistance.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/50227/3062

Comment: Definitely a duplicate. First time I flag my own question.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's possible to dispell it with a mouse.
The reason why you keep failing at dispelling is because there is a small delay when you press mouse,keyboard or controller button,and that delay happens at PC and consoles for lot of people (if not all of them).

You just have to see what kind of delay you have and press the button right before the ring touches the ward (i personally have to press the button right before the ring touches the ward,the delay may be longer for you).

Here is a video guide on how to do it right: [Dispelling guide](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bq2h7GSlEPk)